# Concatenate arrays in Python - output error

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am writing a program to concatenate two numpy arrays and I want the program to print a message for each possible outcome (horizontal, vertical, or no concatenation). I have the following code and I don´t understand why even when the first condition (np.hstack) is met it continues evaluating the subsequent *if* and *else* statements and wrongly prints that there is both a horizontal concatenation (first condition is met) and that a concatenation is not possible.

```
import numpy as np
def fun1(a,b):
    if a.shape[0] == b.shape[0]:
        print("The horizontal concatenation is:", np.hstack((a,b)))
    if a.shape[1] == b.shape[1]:
        print("The vertical concatenation is:", np.vstack((a,b)))
    else:
        print("These arrays cannot be concatenated.")

a = np.floor(10*np.random.random((3,2)))
b = np.floor(10*np.random.random((3,4)))
fun1(a,b)
```

Output:

```
The horizontal concatenation is: [[5. 0. 1. 1. 3. 7.]
                                  [4. 1. 8. 3. 1. 9.]
                                  [9. 1. 5. 7. 0. 0.]]
These arrays cannot be concatenated.
```

Comment: Your second if should probably be an `elif`. As it reads now you have two separate `if` statements.

Comment: The if/else structure is insufficient. To avoid the wrong message you would need if/elif/else as written. But this does not cover the case when both concatenations are possible.

Comment: @mkiver thanks, I corrected it with an elif instead of the second if and now it works. However, I had not considered the case when there is a "perfect" concatenation on both axes - is there a convention that says which axis takes priority then?

Comment: @Madrid_datalady See my answer. With 3 if statements both horizontal and vertical concatenation would be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the else part you need a third if statement with this condition:

```
if a.shape[0] == b.shape[0]:
    print("The horizontal concatenation is:", np.hstack((a,b)))
if a.shape[1] == b.shape[1]:
    print("The vertical concatenation is:", np.vstack((a,b)))
if a.shape[0] != b.shape[0] and a.shape[1] != b.shape[1]:
    print("These arrays cannot be concatenated.")
```